# How to add volume visual feedback to i3 window manager?

Tags: pulseaudio, volume-control, i3-wm

I've set a keybinding for my volume keys using *pulse audio* control command `pactl`:

```
bindsym XF86AudioRaiseVolume exec --no-startup-id "pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ +5%"
```

They work fine but I would like to have also visual feedback of the current volume like some desktop environments has:

[image]

How to achieve that in `i3` or even have the volume (as text value) in the status bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using i3status for your status bar you can look here:

https://i3wm.org/i3status/manpage.html#_volume